# Oracle database with SSL using Java Keystore

Tags: oracle, ssl, oracle12c, jks

I'm looking for guidance on steps to configure an Oracle 12c database to use SSL with JKS. I found a tutorial which was very clear on steps, however, this ended up being for oracle wallets which my client side does not support.

This is simply a test environment so making it simple I'm trying to just use self signed certs. I was able to create a keystore and export a certificate using these commands.

```
keytool -genkey -alias oraclekeystore -keyalg RSA -keypass xxx -storepass xxx -keystore KeyStore.jks -keysize 2048 -validity 1461

keytool -export -keystore KeyStore.jks -alias oraclekeystore -file client.cer
```

And I would use a command similar to below to import on client side with the exception the keystore may already exist but this is the command I found to do the import

```
sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -storepass xxx -noprompt -alias oraclekeystore -file "client.cer"
```

Now the next part on how to configure the database to accept connections using TLS with this keystore/cert is where I'm stuck. I see when using a wallet we would add some configs to sqlnet.ora file

```
WALLET_LOCATION =
   (SOURCE =
     (METHOD = FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
       (DIRECTORY = /u01/app/oracle/wallet)
     )
   )

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (TCPS,NTS,BEQ)
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
```

And set the listener up by stopping the listener, updating listener.ora and starting it again.

```
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE

WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = /u01/app/oracle/wallet)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol7-121.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = ol7-121.localdomain)(PORT = 2484))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle
```

However, I'm unsure how to do this using a JKS and self signed cert without Oracle wallets. Does anyone have experience with this or have set up this scenario? Or any resources which may help to configure the server in this scenario?

Thank you!

Comment: On the server side you'll have to use Oracle wallets, not JKS.

Comment: Thanks @pmdba - If that's the case, how do we export the cert to import into jks on the client side which is ubuntu? Or any way we can still use wallets on client side in that case? From what I could see it doesnt look like the same wallet tools are available on that OS.

Comment: Why do the client and server need to match storage types? A wallet or JKS is only a secure store for the certificate, not the thing (the cert) that is actually compared when establishing the network connection. Once the certificate is loaded by the client and server then the means of storage should not matter. Certificate comparison is governed by TLS, which is already common to both.

Comment: So you're saying I would be able to set up an oracle wallet server side and set up the listener with that. Then generate a cert from the wallet and import that to a jks on the client side and use that when making the connection from client side and this will succeed?

Comment: Certs are generated independently of the storage medium. A wallet or JKS is just a way to store a cert. Your client needs a JKS; the server needs a wallet. Create the certs (one for client, one for server), then load them into the appropriate containers.